# Can a block span more than one region in a theme?

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

Can a block span more than one region in a theme? Sometimes I would like content to do this, depending on the page.

I'm aware (and heavily use) Panels which are great but I thought it would be worth considering other solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not by default, but the [MultiBlock module](http://drupal.org/project/multiblock) will solve this for you, out of the box.

Comment: +1 and Accepted WOW thanks - and for Drupal 7 too! "There's a module for that" :)

Comment: Also try http://drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to consider Panels Everywhere: http://drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere

From the project page:

> "Panels Everywhere is an advanced method to completely do away with
>   Drupal's restrictive blocks system and instead use the much more
>   freeing Panels Layout system to control how your pages look."

A further convincing point, referring to Drupal themes:

> "Panels Everywhere modifies the page as it is being rendered to 'wrap'
>   the content in a display and can even take over your page theme to do
>   away with the need for a page.tpl.php."